# Android - AppWidget's pending intent does not fire

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app widget with a Button in it's layout.
When clicking the button, an intent is fired which calls my broadcast receiver.

It works just fine, but occasionally, after using the "Clear memory" button in the Task Manager, the widget gets stuck - clicking on it does nothing. But it can still receive updates from my app, if its running.

I'm not sure if the fact that the pending intent isn't fired is the memory clearing fault, or my fault.
Anyway, here's the code:

Registering the pending intent (onUpdate method of the app widget)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ServiceControl.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidgetbutton, pendingIntent);
```

and then updating the widgets with the views.

Here is the decleration of the app widget provider:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="72dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0">
</appwidget-provider>
```

I don't want the system to call widget updates, I only update it from my app itself.

So why does the pending intent stop firing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what "Clear memory" does, since Android does not have a "Task Manager" built into the OS. On what version of Android are you testing this?

Comment: Its 2.3.3, and I'm pretty sure that this "Task Manager" is something special for samsung phones. I have tested and got this problem on my Samsung Galaxy S2 and on my dad's S1, so maybe it's this "Clear Memory" fault. By the code I gave, it shouldn't be because something wrong I've done, right?

Comment: Your code looks fine. The one scenario in which I can see your behavior occurring would be on Android 3.1+, if the user kills your app via a task killer or the Manage Services screen in Settings or something. Your app is then moved into a "stopped" state and cannot receive broadcasts until the user manually launches one of your activities again. The "Clear memory" might be some variation of a task killer, but I'm pretty sure the no-more-broadcasts rule did not come into effect until Android 3.1.

Comment: After the app stops receiving broadcasts, you MUST delete the widget, it will never receive broadcasts again (It will never receive MY broadcasts. broadcasts like APPWIDGET_UPDATE are still received). But I'm wondering, why isn't it happening in any other widgets? No other widget has never got stuck so I still feel like its my fault, somewhere...

Comment: I've had a user report this issue as well, on their Samsung Galaxy Note.

Comment: @Jong I'm stuck in exactly the same situation as you. Did you by any chance find the actual bug?

Comment: No, I haven't. Sorry :(

Comment: @Jong I think I've got the same problem, have you find a solution? Using the APPWIDGET_UPDATE doesn't seem to be a way since it's triggered not only when the user clicks on the remote view :(

Answer (score 1):

@Jong

@CommonsWare

Hi guys, I figured it out. Ofc this is an Android issue, the receiver should ALWAYS receive. 
Now how to get around it? Obviously all the widgets are working, so there must have been a simple out there.

I read on SO somewhere (trying to find the guy) reminding us all that the widget class is actually extending a BroadcastReceiver.

So, you could register the widget (in the manifest) to receive the threats itself. Thus the entire system is self-contained in the class instance of AppWidgetProvider.

Now, for communicating back with the app, you can in the onReceive call any static class of your app, and LocalBroadcastManager won't fail you if the app is active. If it's not active, your buttons should be starting activities anyway!

Should you want the code, I can detail it.